# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') error

Tags: ios, swift

```
let str = "<h1>Test</h1><h2>Test2</h2><h3>Hello, playground</h3><h3>Test</h3>"
str.split(separator: "<h3>")
```

I have the code above, and I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below code instead of your 2nd line?

```
    str.components(separatedBy: "<h3>")
```